# Source code different than code being built

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-applications

I'm having an issue with a Visual Studio 2008 web application project where changes I make to the form or the code behind do not get built when debugging, and so I cannot use breakpoints and in fact none of the changes I make will display unless I navigate to "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files" and delete the "root" folder therein.  So my debugging and development process involves me making changes, then closing Visual Studio 2008, deleting this folder, then re-opening Visual Studio and compiling.  I've had the same problem using 2010 as well.  My code lives on my C: drive.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a rights issue? Possibly the ASP.NET Machine Account doesn't have the rights. The pain in the ass thing to do seems to run DiskMon to see if .NET is trying to delete the files in the directory.

Comment: Where is DiskMon? Should .NET be deleting files in this directory?  It seems like it needs to delete these so my changes get propogated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues like this before (though maybe not exactly the same). Delete the .dll & .pdb files and try it again.. also make sure you project is turned on for debugging.

Comment: I've tried deleting this files but to no avail.  The project is being compiled in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Configuration Manager you can change the configuration for your project. Change this to `debug`.

Comment: I've confirmed that it's being compiled in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a rebuild? I don't know why your code isn't updating on build, but sometimes building from scratch fixes the problem.